# yii2 copy of application as separate applications on same server

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, oauth-2.0, routes, yii2

i have one application running in yii2 without any issue. i got some requirment under which i have to make copy of existing yii2 application and rename it as different application with copy of existing database as new database on same server. It mean server is having two folder having same code with different name.

My problem is in new instance i have installed oauth2 package to use it in apis, but same is reflecting in the other application as well. Seems like it taking configuration globaly which is affecting the other application.

ALso i have checked that for routes below

http://server/firstapplication/api/web/v1/main/userlogin

and

http://server/secondapplication/api/web/v1/main/userlogin

it is always directing to first application. Unable to reactify the setting in yii2. i am just new to yii framework. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

create 2 folder in /var/www/html like oldcode and newcode

Now you have to create virtual host in conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/oldcode"
    ServerName oldcode.com.
    ErrorLog "logs/oldcode.admin-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/oldcode.admin-access.log" common
    <Directory />
        #Options FollowSymLinks
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/newcode"
    ServerName newcode.com.
    ErrorLog "logs/newcode.admin-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/newcode.admin-access.log" common
    <Directory />
        #Options FollowSymLinks
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```